# When can I expect multiple "choices" in an OpenAI response?

Tags: openai-api

For a simple OpenAI api call in python

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-4",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": instructions},
        {"role": "user", "content": my_input}
    ])
```

I get meaningful data in `response['choices'][0]['message']['content']`

Under what circumstances will there be multiple entries in `response['choices']`? How should I interpret this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see, the documentation says that if you set the parameter `n` to more than 1 you will get more than one "`choice`".

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create

> n integer or null Optional Defaults to 1
>
> How many chat completion
> choices to generate for each input message. Note that you will be
> charged based on the number of generated tokens across all of the
> choices. Keep n as 1 to minimize costs.

I don't know the concept behind naming it `choices`, but I can tell you that the default is `1`, so you always will have to access index `0` from `choices` unless you change the `n` parameter.